# How to implement the modified source code of Tor?

Tags: circuit, source-code, ubuntu

I want to log how many circuits have been made through my Tor onion router (OR). So if I do some changes in the original source code, how can I make my Tor use that changed source code. I am now using Tor version 0.2.4.21 controlled by Vidalia 0.2.21 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

In general you do the following steps:

1. Check the source code from [Tor's git repository](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git) or from the [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en).
2. Apply your changes
3. Compile the code (`./configure && make`)
4. You can install the binary (`make install`) or run it directly from the directory (`src/or/tor`)

As long as you do the changes you mentioned there is no need to exclude you from the network. In fact usually nobody has a chance to find out that you did it. However when you makes changes to the protocol or the network behaviour of Tor this will get noticed and you might get blocked.

So if you want to do testing with Tor you have the chance to build a private Tor network. All changes you make will only affect this network. [Shadow](https://shadow.cs.umn.edu/) is one of the projects which help to build such a private network.