# How to modify Tor source code in Shadow

Tags: source-code

For research purposes I'd like to implement my modified version of the Tor source code in the Shadow simulation network, but I am not exactly sure how to do that. Shadow uses a plug-in called Scallion that is a wrapper for the Tor source code. This solved question ([How to implement the modified source code of Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/how-to-implement-the-modified-source-code-of-tor)) merely mentions the idea, but could someone please explain to me clearly the steps of doing modifications in Shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is the same as modifying the Tor source code without using Shadow: simply modify the .torrc files. An explanation of this is available:  [Editing .torrc in Tor Browser Bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/what-happened-to-torrc-in-tor-browser-bundle)